# Build failed with Realm and circleCI (with Carthage)

Tags: ios, swift, realm, circleci, carthage

I keep getting linker error when running my project on circleCI saying that realm framework is not found. I have no problem with the framework on my development environment. I have checked the framework search path to include both $(inherited) and carthage build folder ($(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS). Below are the content of both my cartfile and circle.yml (circleCI's configuration file)

## cartfile

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.4
github "Alamofire/AlamofireImage" ~> 2.0
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" ~> 2.3.0
github "SnapKit/SnapKit" >= 0.15.0
github "realm/realm-cocoa"
```

## circle.yml

```
machine:
  xcode:
    version: "7.3"

dependencies:
  pre:
    - curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cabeca/cbaacbeb6a1cc4683aa5/raw/8e17f39f5a7413fd0559c9e6808e01b6fb514422/simulator_populator
    - ruby ./simulator_populator
    - carthage update --platform iOS
```

The 2 lines before `carthage update` are suggested by circleCI support tech to avoid issues with tvOS framework. I have also tried switching `carthage update` to `carthage bootstrap` with the same result. Below are the error message I get
[image]

From the screenshot it seems like the error occurs when it tries to link test files, but both test and uitest files are default created by xcode, I haven't added anything on it yet

Answer (score 0):

> but both test and uitest files are default created by xcode, I haven't added anything on it yet

I think that's the problem here. You need to make sure that both targets can find the framework via the build setting `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`. This should include the parent directory of the relevant frameworks, e.g. `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS`. You can achieve that usually by dragging or adding the framework(s) to the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

not

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```